# Нахождение самого часто повторяющегося (повторяющихся) значений в массиве

Tags: c++, алгоритм

В массиве надо найти самое(самые) часто повторяющееся(повторяющиеся) числа.

1. При этом нужно вывести всех их, если есть одинаковое число повторяющихся: массив "1 8 3 4 4 1", то должно быть выведено: 1 1 4 4.
2. А если только одно значение повторяется много раз, то из них должно быть выведено только одно. массив "2, 2, 2, 5, 7", ответ: 2.
3. Если повторяющихся совсем нет то ничего не должно вывестись.

У меня только 2 пункт не выполняется, как можно исправить? Код на с++.

```
int main()
    {
        int max{}, postmax{}, index{}; const int n = 5; bool flag = false;
        int mas[n] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
    
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                if (i == j) continue;
                if (mas[i] == mas[j])
                {
                    postmax++;
                }
            }
    
            if (postmax > max) {
                max = postmax;
                index = i;
                flag = true;
            }
            else {
                if (postmax == max && max != 0) {
                    cout << mas[index] << endl;
                    index = i;
                }
            }
            postmax = 0;
        }
    
        if (flag) cout << mas[index] << endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Исправил вопрос.

Comment: Отсортировать массив (одинаковые числа окажутся рядом) и последовательно смотреть его, подсчитывая число повторов

Comment: Сортировка создает дополнительные действия, чего нужно  избегать.

Answer (score 1):

раз можно использовать c++ (и стандартные библиотеки соответственно), то я бы делал в лоб

1. использовал бы словарь `std::map<int, int>`
2. прошелся бы по всем числам в массиве и если числа нет в словаре, добавлял бы `(число, 1)` иначе увеличивал бы значение, соответствующее числу

после этого в словаре содержатся числа и сколько раз они встречаются

3. дальше прошел бы по всем ключам слова и определил бы 1 из 3х состояний - вообще нет повторений (все значения равны 1), есть одно повторение (только одно значение больше 1), есть несколько повторений
4. на основании шага 3) вывел бы соответствующий результат

Comment: Как можно в цикле обратится к последующему элементу map, чтобы сравнить его с текущим? Так как итератор map невозможно сложить с числом.

Comment: @Anvar, ничто не мешает составить список (вектор) ключей и перемещаться по ним уже используя численные индексы

Comment: А почему (iterator + 1) или iterator.begin() + 1, как в векторе не работает с map?

Comment: потому что в словаре не используется итератор общего доступа (или как он там называется), когда вы можете на произвольный элемент перейти, а только `++`, чтобы перейти на следующий - если я конечно не путаю, т.е. в итераторе для словаря не определены операции `+` и `-`

Comment: ок благодарю спасибо

Comment: Предложенное вами решение оказалось структурным (структура данных), структуры не решают условия задачи (1 2 3). А мне нужно алгоритмическое решение. Ни карты ни вектора не помогают это решить. Если учитывать ограничения связанные с итераторами карты и уникальностью ключей, то становится еще сложно.

Comment: выверните словарь обратно в виде `std::map<int, std::vector<int>>` и все решится - ищите где вектор содержит больше 1 элемента, это если в лоб сразу решать, над красивым решением можно и подумать, но опять же - можно двухпроходный вариант с одним вектором предложить, что еще лучше и решает задачу

Comment: первым проходом вы вычисляете повторяющиеся элементы и их частоту, а вторым проходом вы вычисляете есть ли повторения или нет

Comment: Я вот именно так и сделал, когда вы написали решение. Но именно ни это мне нужно))). Значит нет другого выхода в этой ситуации. Спасибо (На счет map<int, vector<int>> я подумаю)

Comment: почему не это вам нужно? на первом проходе вы собираете информацию о частотных данных, а на втором проверяете все 3 условия, которые вам и нужны

Comment: Да я теперь понял что иначе невозможно решить, просто ожидал что может быть.